# Php/kohana error when running install portion of beansbooks

Tags: php, ubuntu, kohana

#### Problem

I have installed **beansbooks** and I'm at the last step, but when I go to localhost/install, I get the following error:

> A fatal error has occurred: Session_Exception [ 1 ]: Error reading session data.exception 'ErrorException' with message
> 'mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given'
> in
> /var/www/html/modules/database/classes/kohana/database/mysql.php:105
> Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Kohana_Core::error_handler(2,
> 'mysql_select_db...', '/var/www/html/m...', 105, Array) #1
> /var/www/html/modules/database/classes/kohana/database/mysql.php(105):
> mysql_select_db('kohana', false) #2
> /var/www/html/application/classes/database/mysql.php(75):
> Kohana_Database_MySQL->_select_db('kohana') #3
> /var/www/html/modules/database/classes/kohana/database/mysql.php(430):
> Database_MySQL->connect() #4
> /var/www/html/modules/database/classes/kohana/database.php(478):
> Kohana_Database_MySQL->escape('5c8da306617b91-...') #5 [internal
> function]: Kohana_Database->quote('5c8da306617b91-...') #6
> /var/www/html/modules/database/classes/kohana/database/query.php(190):
> array_map(Array, Array) #7
> /var/www/html/modules/database/classes/kohana/database/query/builder/select.php(413):
> Kohana_Database_Query->compile(Object(Database_MySQL)) #8
> /var/www/html/modules/database/classes/kohana/database/query.php(228):
> Kohana_Database_Query_Builder_Select->compile(Object(Database_MySQL))
>
> ## 9 /var/www/html/modules/database/classes/kohana/session/database.php(131):
>
> Kohana_Database_Query->execute(Object(Database_MySQL)) #10
> /var/www/html/modules/database/classes/kohana/session/database.php(111):
> Kohana_Session_Database->_regenerate() #11
> /var/www/html/system/classes/kohana/session.php(300):
> Kohana_Session_Database->_read(NULL) #12
> /var/www/html/system/classes/kohana/session.php(125):
> Kohana_Session->read(NULL) #13
> /var/www/html/modules/database/classes/kohana/session/database.php(74):
> Kohana_Session->__construct(Array, NULL) #14
> /var/www/html/system/classes/kohana/session.php(54):
> Kohana_Session_Database->__construct(Array, NULL) #15
> /var/www/html/application/classes/controller/view.php(49):
> Kohana_Session::instance() #16
> /var/www/html/application/classes/controller/exception.php(27):
> Controller_View->before() #17 [internal function]:
> Controller_Exception->before() #18
> /var/www/html/system/classes/kohana/request/client/internal.php(103):
> ReflectionMethod->invoke(Object(Controller_Exception)) #19
> /var/www/html/system/classes/kohana/request/client.php(64):
> Kohana_Request_Client_Internal->execute_request(Object(Request)) #20
> /var/www/html/system/classes/kohana/request.php(1154):
> Kohana_Request_Client->execute(Object(Request)) #21
> /var/www/html/application/classes/kohana/exception.php(25):
> Kohana_Request->execute() #22 [internal function]:
> Kohana_Exception::handler(Object(Session_Exception)) #23 {main} ~
> SYSPATH/classes/kohana/session.php [ 325 ]

How do I solve this problem?

#### System

> php5
>
> Ubuntu 14.04
>
> Mysql 5.5
>
> apache2

Comment: did you add your config based on this: https://github.com/system76/beansbooks/blob/master/application/classes/beans/example.config.php ?

Answer (score 0):

You have problems connecting to the database, because the resource is not returned, just error.

You have several options:

- re-checking the connection data in config
- switching to PDO database driver
- fast hack in the library:

in `MODPATH\database\classes\Kohana\Database\MySQL.php` method  `connect()` before: `$this->_select_db($database);` you add:

```php
if(!$this->_connection)
  throw new Database_Exception(':error',
            array(':error' => mysql_error()),
            mysql_errno());
```

NOTE: There is a problem with PDO that does not support automatic discovery of model. But to debug the connection is enough.

Umm, this can be done according to the art, without modifying the modules:

create file: `APPPATH\classes\Database\MySQL.php`

```php
class Database_MySQL extends Kohana_Database_MySQL{
  protected function _select_db($database) {
    if(!$this->_connection)
      throw new Database_Exception(':error',
            array(':error' => mysql_error()),
            mysql_errno());
    return parent::_select_db($database);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, I did all that and I got a bit further now I also created a case here:

https://github.com/system76/beansbooks/issues/277

It is complaining about some account_types not being present they didn't get created during the install process.